# tesseract.js recognize from axios stream response

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, tesseract

My question is it possible to recognize from tesseract.js from axios response stream

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { TesseractWorker } = require('tesseract.js');
const worker = new TesseractWorker();

axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/iXmJ9aWblkGDpg-_jpcqaY10KmA8HthjZ7F15U7mJ9PQK6vZEStMlathz1FfQQWV5XeeF-A1tZ0UpDjx3q6vEm2BWZn5k1btVSuBk9ad=s660',
  responseType: 'stream'
})
  .then(function (response) {
    //this doesn't work
    worker.recognize(response.data).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  });
```

I see some examples https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/580/how-to-convert-images-to-text-with-pure-javascript-using-tesseract-js & https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/348/getting-started-with-optical-character-recognition-ocr-with-tesseract-in-node-js.

But I can't figure out from this examples.

> -----------------------------------------------------Update--------------------------------------------------------------------

After debugging I found it's not a problem with tesseract.js as it's calling native node.js fs readFile function https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/src/node/index.js#L37

So facing problem with readFile now on how to readFile from axios response. Which is also not possible. As readFile accepts only path not data. So will be creating an issue to tesseract.js so that while recognize readFile can be bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this library, but from the given examples and a quick inspection of their source code, it looks like `worker.recognize` doesn't accept a stream as an argument, instead it expect either an image url or an actual image and it handles the network call "if needed" internally.

https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/src/common/TesseractWorker.js#L74

```
const { TesseractWorker } = require( 'tesseract.js' );
const worker = new TesseractWorker();


worker.recognize('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/iXmJ9aWblkGDpg-_jpcqaY10KmA8HthjZ7F15U7mJ9PQK6vZEStMlathz1FfQQWV5XeeF-A1tZ0UpDjx3q6vEm2BWZn5k1btVSuBk9ad=s660')
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
```

Comment: If you see https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/580/how-to-convert-images-to-text-with-pure-javascript-using-tesseract-js there is clearly stated that you can use a Buffer instance containing a PNG or JPEG image or a ImageData instance (an object containing width, height and data properties). Thanks for your response.

Comment: in that case, which version do you use? 

try to install their latest version

`npm install tesseract.js@next`

Answer (score 0):

In axios, you can change the `responseType` to `arraybuffer` in case of Node.js, or `blob` in case of browser. and pass the result to `Tesseract.recognize`

For Example,

```
const img = await axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'your img url',
  responseType: 'arraybuffer' //for me it's node.js
});
const imgeDataAsString = await Tesseract.recognize(
  img.data,
  'eng',
  { logger: m => console.log(m) }
).then(({ data: { text } }) => text);
```

You refer the axios doc [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)